# Not able to establish connection between mongodb and Springboot through app.properties file

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I want to establish connection with mongodb through app.properties files in Spring boot.
Currently, I am establishing connection through Uri variable declared in the  class file itself.

```
private static String uri ="mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false";

private static String database = "xyz";
```

When I am trying to configure it in app.properties files like this

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri= mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false
spring.data.mongodb.database = xyz
```

It is not connecting and I am getting this error

```
Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "connectionString" is null
```